# Do Transient, Singleton, and Scoped life time matter when injecting static fields?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a console app that makes use of EF Core as follows.

```
static class Program
{
    private static readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    static Program()
    {
        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection isc)
    {
        isc.AddSingleton(_ => _configuration);

        // others are removed for simplicity
        isc.AddSingleton<TheApp>();
    }

    public static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
    {
        // create service collection
        IServiceCollection isc = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(isc);

        // create service provider
        return isc.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create application instance and run
        using (var scope = CreateServiceProvider().CreateScope())
        {
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TheApp>().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

There are `Singleton`, `Transient`, `Scoped` life times. Which one is appropriate for the static field `_configuration` above? Does the life time matter?

Comment: Why would you use static here in the first place? Why not just inject the configuration as needed?

Comment: @mason: I have no idea if there is any other better way to do so.

Comment: Why not just inject the configuration as needed? That's what the whole point of DI is. Getting dependencies into classes and managing their lifetimes.

Comment: @mason: I think I already injected the configuration in my code above.

Comment: For a console app? I doubt it matters which LifeTime you use really...

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity No, you haven't injected it. You just manually set it in a static constructor. Then you registered it with your container. Why not remove the static constructor, eliminate the static field, and simply register the configuration with your container? Then when any class in your app needs IConfiguration, it can ask for it via constructor injection.

Comment: The DI container doesn't have control of the lifetime because *you already created the instance you want to use*. It's already alive and the factory method you're provided to the container is a lie - it's not a factory, it's handing back something already constructed. **Hopefully** telling it it's a singleton would wind up biting you.

Comment: Would be better if you used the overload of `AddSingleton` that accepts an instance rather than a factory.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks. I just understood what you said.

Answer (score 1):

`Singleton`, because once you set a configuration, you should only be using that one configuration.

Comment: As `_configuration` is shared in the application domain, does using `Transient` and `Scoped` make difference in allocating resources?